# how to join two differents dataframes in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes  one  with columns of X year,month and measure, and
  columns with  x1, x2 which  corresonds to  the first day and the second 
  day . The first dataframe is:

```
X year month                   measure                   X1        X2
1     1 2014    12          Max.TemperatureF             64        42
2     2 2014    12         Mean.TemperatureF             52        38
3     3 2014    12          Min.TemperatureF             39        33
```

The second dataframe where only I have the days.

```
         X3   X4      X5    X6    X7
         1    51      43    42    45    
         2    44      37    34    42    
         3    37      30    26    38
```

So I want to join the two dataframes and obtain in pyspark

```
 X year month                 measure          X1   X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  
'1     1 2014    12       Max.TemperatureF     64   42  1   51  43  42     
'2     2 2014    12       Mean.TemperatureF    52   38  2   44  37  34  
'3     3 2014    12       Min.TemperatureF     39   33  3   37  30  26
```

I have joined them but they get one dataframe above the another dataframe instead of that they remain in the same rows

```
  from functools import reduce 
  from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


  def unionAll(*dfs):
  return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

  td = unionAll(*[weather1, weather2])

        X year month             measure               X1        X2
      1     1 2014    12          Max.TemperatureF     64        42
      2     2 2014    12         Mean.TemperatureF     52        38
      3     3 2014    12          Min.TemperatureF     39        33
            X3      X4    X5    X6    
       1    51      43    42    45    
       2    44      37    34    42    
       3    37      30    26    38
```

So this is a wrong joining .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you are trying to do is join two tables. To join two tables, you need a common column and since you don't have a common column, you will have to create something. This is how I would tackle this:

```
# Copy the entire 'X' column (which I am assuming is the index)
weather2 = weather2.withColumn('X', weather1['X'])

# Join the two tables on 'X'
joinExpr = 'X'
td = weather1.join(weather2, joinExpr)
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Joining two differents dataframes in pyspark?

Assuming

1. two DataFrame to be df and df1 respectively
2. X1 as common column in two dataframe

   `sqlContext.sql( "select * from df, df1 where df.X1 == df1.X1").show()`